# Elastic Beanstalk: duration of environment creation vs immutable deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Playing around with environments on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EB), I noticed that *creating* a new single instance environment is much faster than *immutable deployment* to that same environment (using the exact same application version).

I'm talking about **3 minutes** vs **14 minutes**, respectively, before the environment health is "OK."

Can anyone explain this?

Probably my concept of environment vs instance is wrong, but I would expect the difference (if any) to be the other way round.

Here's a minimal example of the workflow:

1. Use the EB (web) management console to create a new single instance environment, using the default Python/Amazon-Linux and default sample application. The default configuration was only changed to set the deployment policy to "immutable," instead of "all at once," before starting environment creation. This takes approx. **3 minutes**:

   ```
   2018-10-17 12:14:17 UTC+0200    INFO    Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Ok. Initialization completed 33 seconds ago and took 3 minutes.
   2018-10-17 12:13:39 UTC+0200    INFO    Successfully launched environment: create-vs-deploy
   ```
2. From the "Application versions" page select the sample-application (i.e. the exact same application version used in step 1), and deploy (immutable) that to the environment created in step 1. This takes approx. **14 minutes**:

   ```
   2018-10-17 12:36:16 UTC+0200    INFO    Environment health has transitioned from Info to Ok. Application update completed 67 seconds ago and took 14 minutes.
   ```

The same holds for subsequent deployments, and similar results with custom app versions.

The `eb-activity.log` files for both instances have identical commands and output, and the duration from start to `Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup succeeded` is also nearly identical: both little over 1 minute.

The log for the immutable deployment then shows some additional lines starting more than 6 minutes later:

```
[2018-10-17T10:22:10.227Z] INFO  [2269]  - [Initialization] : Starting activity...
...
[2018-10-17T10:23:21.610Z] INFO  [2620]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@2/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2018-10-17T10:23:21.610Z] INFO  [2620]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@2] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup succeeded
[2018-10-17T10:29:58.110Z] INFO  [3055]  - [Re-associating instance] : Starting activity...
...
[2018-10-17T10:29:58.115Z] INFO  [3055]  - [Re-associating instance] : Completed activity. Result:
  Re-associating instance - Command CMD-ImmutableDeploymentFlip succeeded
```

Any idea what is going on during the 6 minute pause? Is EB waiting for health checks for 6 minutes each time?

Also, there is a big difference between the approx. 8 minutes duration from start to finish in the `eb-activity.log`, and the 14 minutes reported by the Events page.

Not sure if it helps, but this is from the `healthd/daemon.log` for the immutable deployment:

```
# Logfile created on 2018-10-17 10:22:04 +0000 by logger.rb/47272
A, [2018-10-17T10:22:05.218449 #2186]   ANY -- : healthd daemon 1.0.3 initialized
W, [2018-10-17T10:22:05.369315 #2186]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/httpd/healthd/application.log.2018-10-17-10" does not exist
...
W, [2018-10-17T10:23:16.646199 #2186]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/httpd/healthd/application.log.2018-10-17-10" does not exist
W, [2018-10-17T10:36:55.231184 #2186]  WARN -- : discarding statistic item after validation error (Invalid timestamp): {:id=>"0", :namespace=>"application", :timestamp=>1539771800, :data=>"{\"duration\":10,\"latency_histogram\":[[0.213,1]],\"http_counters\":{\"status_200\":1,\"request_count\":1}}"}
```

The log for the newly created env looks identical except for the last line.

Additional info:

From the Events below (same app deployed at a different time) I assume that the new instance takes over about 12 minutes after the application update started, after which the old instance is terminated etc.

```
2018-10-17 14:29:07 UTC+0200    INFO    Environment health has transitioned from Info to Ok. Application update completed 37 seconds ago and took 13 minutes.
2018-10-17 14:28:38 UTC+0200    INFO    Environment update completed successfully.
2018-10-17 14:28:38 UTC+0200    INFO    New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
2018-10-17 14:28:07 UTC+0200    INFO    Removed instance [i-0*******] from your environment.
2018-10-17 14:26:25 UTC+0200    INFO    Deployment succeeded. Terminating old instances and temporary Auto Scaling group.
2018-10-17 14:24:36 UTC+0200    INFO    Waiting for post-deployment configuration to complete.
2018-10-17 14:24:31 UTC+0200    INFO    Starting post-deployment configuration on new instances.
2018-10-17 14:23:31 UTC+0200    INFO    Attached new instance(s) to the permanent auto scaling group awseb-e-******-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup*****.
2018-10-17 14:23:29 UTC+0200    INFO    Detached new instance(s) from temporary auto scaling group awseb-e-******-immutable-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup*****.
2018-10-17 14:19:32 UTC+0200    INFO    Waiting for instance(s) (i-0******) to pass health checks.
2018-10-17 14:17:08 UTC+0200    INFO    Added instance [i-0******] to your environment.
2018-10-17 14:17:08 UTC+0200    INFO    Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Info. Application update in progress on 1 instance. 0 out of 1 instance completed (running for 2 minutes).
2018-10-17 14:15:19 UTC+0200    INFO    Created temporary auto scaling group awseb-e-*****-immutable-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-*******.
2018-10-17 14:14:33 UTC+0200    INFO    Immutable deployment policy enabled. Launching one instance with the new settings to verify health.
2018-10-17 14:14:24 UTC+0200    INFO    Environment update is starting.
```

Comment: Having similar issues, previously a deploy taking 20 seconds takes 12 minutes when set to immutable.

Comment: @BookOfGreg: Not sure if it will help you, but you can find the answer I received from AWS support below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that a lot more is involved in immutable deployments than in environment creation. Here is part of the response I received from *AWS support*, explaining the differences more clearly than I ever could:

> ### What will happen on environment creation
>
> 1) The new environment creation command is issued
>
> 2) A CloudFormation stack is created to launch the resources
>   associated with the environment
>
> 3) The instance or instances that will be launched as part of the
>   AutoScaling group are provisioned: this implies to execute, in that
>   particular case, CMD-StartUp which will execute also all the hooks
>   associated. At this time the environment is provisioned.
>
> ### What will happen on Immutable Deployments
>
> 1) A new CloudFormation stack is created to so the current one is not
>   getting modified
>
> 2) One instance is being launched in a temporary AutoScaling group
>
> 3) The instance is provisioned the same way as the existing one was
>   at environment creation with CMD-StartUp
>
> 4) The instance, once ready, is added to the environment's load
>   balancer
>
> 5) The instance has to pass all health checks. If the environment is
>   of type "Web server", it needs to pass 12 consecutive health checks;
>   if the environment is of type "worker", it needs to pass 18 health
>   checks. Since Enhanced health check is reporting the status every 10
>   seconds, it means that in the best possible scenario, this is going to
>   take 2 minutes (10 x 12 = 120). (More information regarding this [1])
>
> 6) The "CMD-ImmutableDeploymentFlip" command needs to be executed on
>   the new instance/instances, which will then call the
>   "infra-reregister-cfn-hup.rb" script and performs different actions
>
> 7) Post-deployment configuration starts
>
> 8) When deployment succeeded, the old instance(s) needs to be
>   terminated
>
> 9) The deployment is completed.